# Is the following true: For the process $y_t =0.879y_{t-1} + e_t$, less than 60% of the value of five periods ago is still reflected in current period?

Tags: autoregressive

I know that the process is AR(1) and some of the data is still reflected in this period. But can we just take the power of $5$ of $0.879$?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for "data" to be "reflected" in a particular period? We know that $f(y_t | y_{(t-1)}, y_{(t-2)}, \ldots, y_1) = f(y_t | y_{(t-1)})$ because the process is AR1. On the other hand $cov(Y_t, Y_{t-5}) > 0$. The arithmetic is simple, but just taking $\beta$ to the power of 5 is not motivated yet. Another question might be what is the result of the regression of $E[Y_t | Y_{t-5}] = \beta^* Y_{t-5} + \epsilon^{*}t$

Comment: From my understanding I think the data to be reflected is that the value of it still affected the present value. The question I received is only in the title of this question.

Comment: Can you begin answering the question when "five periods" is replaced by "one period"?  If not, why not?  If so, what about with "two periods"?